# Updating Access database with CSV file

Tags: ms-access, csv, vba

I have an **access database** that contains **4 tables** . Now I want to **update** the values of these four tables woth **four csv files** everyday and then save the entire copy of the aceess database . Please let me know how is this possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Ms Access to import Text Files using either delimiters or fixed width (in your case, it's comma-separated values, i.e. CSV). Starting with Access 2007, it's located under **ExternalData->TextFile** menu option. Usage is very intuitive - just follow the online wizards dialogs. 
If you want to automate this process w/VBA, then use the statement like following sample:

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImportCSV", FileName:="C:\[YourOriginalDataFile].csv", HasFieldNames:=true
```

where **tblImportCSV** is the Access Table; **C:[YourOriginalDataFile].csv** is the original CSV data file (source)

Rgds.

Comment: I cannot do that because I cannot make a new blank database everyday as I have already wrtten queries in my original database. Any solution ?

Comment: You do not need to make a new DB: use the same one, the same data table(s), just delete all records in that table before importing new data set from CSV file. Rgds,